# Finite Ring with unity and no zero divisors is field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, integral-domain, finite-rings

I would like to know if someone can help me with this.

"Show that a finite ring $R$ with unity $1\neq 0$ and no divisors of 0 is a field."

The original exercise asked me to show that it was a division ring, it's done. It also says that showing that commutativity holds is hard. I wonder, is it too hard? If it isn't, how could I show that?

Comment: Look up "Weddenburn's Theorem on finite division rings." It is a rather involved one.

Comment: Oh, that's it,.